# Where to find the Carja War Bow?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I can't find the Carja war bow in Horizon Zero Dawn. Where and when in the game can you buy one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://m.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/War_Bows):

> This is the Blue variant of the weapon and **can be obtained after reaching Daytower** for the price of 300 Metal Shards, 5 Desert Glass and 2 Slagshine Glass. It has 50 handling and 2 mod slots.

I can't tell you for sure which exact merchants will have it available, but the Meridian merchant sells all weapons available, so if you can't find it elsewhere, go there. Being the *Carja* War Bow, however, (and based on the guide), I believe you can find it at any merchant in Carja, as the Daytower is the gate into Carja territory.

Comment: Do you ever sleep? You always beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I sleep occasionally